# How to run query from inside of Cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to perform a query on my database once a cloud function on my Firebase app is called.

Let's say I have a certain trigger on the database, consider the example provided in the [get started guide on Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions).

```
// Listens for new messages added to /messages/:pushId/original and creates an
// uppercase version of the message to /messages/:pushId/uppercase
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
  .onWrite(event => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original = event.data.val();
      console.log('Uppercasing', event.params.pushId, original);
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      // I'D LIKE TO PERFORM A QUERY HERE, JUST A SIMPLE RETRIEVE BASED ON THE ID PROVIDED
     // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
     // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
     // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
     return event.data.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
});
```

Which *modules* should I import, if any?
How can I perform the query on the DB?

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [Node.js Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) for this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.makeUppercase = functions.database()
  .ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
  .onWrite(event => {
    return admin.database().ref('/other')
      .orderByChild('id').equalTo(event.params.pushId)
      .once('value').then(snapshot => {
        // there, I queried!
      });
  });
```

Comment: Not quite working.... I tried this.. admin.database().ref('chats/g1/push-key-1').toJSON().valueOf('id') ... But it doesn't seem to be returning the vlaue.

Comment: it's `database().` and not `database.`