# Firebase cloud function to get data snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a cloud function so i can get my data and then filter it out.
I am new to cloud functions but this is what i wrote so far:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const database = admin.database();
const rootRef = database.ref("opps/opp");
exports.getRecentOpps = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  rootRef.then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(k) {
      console.log(k);
      res.send(k);
    });
  });

  res.status(200).end();
});
```

Any idea how to read the data snapshot from firebase db?

Comment: You'd use the `admin` SDK for that (it's already imported on line 2 of your code). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868592/how-to-run-query-from-inside-of-cloud-function/42869266#42869266. While that one is trigged from a database write, you'd use the exact same approach in a HTTP-triggered function.

Comment: I updated it but i get error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON. Here is my code:    exports.getRecentOpps = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
                                                  return database.ref('/opps').once('value').then(snapshot => {
                                                                       res.send(snapshot) }); });