# google cloud function to firebase database with storage trigger

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to create a cloud function triggered by a storage trigger which writes data into a firebase database. It seems that only during a database trigger can the cloud function talk to the firebase database.

So I want to know does anyone have an example for that or tell me if it is possible for a Google Cloud function to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions can be triggered from [uploads to Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events), or through [writes to the Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). The [samples repo on Github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) has examples for both.

Comment: I want to use storage trigger to trigger the cloud function, and then the cloud function needs to write data into firebase database. In that repo, the only way to write data into firebase database is to use realtime database trigger which is not what I want. But Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at this sample, which shows how to modify the database from a HTTP function: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/3b41b2e04d854a821a0149e1e5b0769bad397d67/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/index.js#L32. Also see this answer from fellow Firebaser Michael: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868592/how-to-run-query-from-inside-of-cloud-function/42869266#42869266

Comment: Yes. It works. Thanks!