# Retrieve multiple data from firebase database in one cloud function

Tags: javascript, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am faced with the problem of retrieving two data values of a single node from my firebase database and reference it in my javascript file but don't know how to go about it. I have been able to retrieve just one data value from a node (in this case "message") but I would like to add "from" as well. Most tutorials just reference one so I am really confused. So how do I get multiple data values? 
This is my code...

**JS file**

```
exports.sendNotification7 = functions.database.ref('/GroupChat/{Modules}/SDevtChat/{SDevtChatId}/message')
.onWrite(( change,context) =>{

// Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
var eventSnapshot = change.after.val();
var str = "New message from System Development Group Chat: " + eventSnapshot;
console.log(eventSnapshot);

var topic = "Management.Information.System";
var payload = {
    data: {
        name: str,
        click_action: "Student_SystemsDevt"

    }
};

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
    .then(function (response) {
        // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
        // contents of response.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        return;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
});
```

[image: Database Snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trigger your function one level higher in the JSON:

```
exports.sendNotification7 = 
functions.database.ref('/GroupChat/{Modules}/SDevtChat/{SDevtChatId}')
.onWrite(( change,context) =>{

    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var eventSnapshot = change.after.val();
    console.log(eventSnapshot);
    var str = "New message from System Development Group Chat: " + eventSnapshot.message;
    var from = eventSnapshot.from;

    ...
```

Comment: It worked like a charm Frank! Please but what about referencing a different node altogether?

Comment: My answer addresses reading from other places in the database

Comment: You can use the Admin SDK for that. See TerPro's answer or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913139/firebase-http-cloud-functions-read-database-once and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868592/how-to-run-query-from-inside-of-cloud-function/42869266#42869266

Comment: Hello Frank. What about the sender value? Can't seem to retrieve it.

Comment: Figured it outtttttt!! Thanks everyone!!

Comment: `eventSnapshot.sender`?

Answer (score 3):

You can read from however many nodes you want in a Cloud Function. However, only one can trigger the function to run.

To read from your database use the following code:

```
admin.database().ref('/your/path/here').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

var value = snapshot.val();

});
```

You will probably want to read from the same place that the Cloud Function was triggered. Use context.params.PARAMETER to get this information. For the example you posted your code would turn out looking something like this:

```
admin.database().ref('/GroupChat/'+context.params.Modules+'/SDevtChat/'+context.params.SDevtChatId+'/from').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

var value = snapshot.val();

});
```