# How to update a document value with firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How can i update the value of a document on changing the value of another document.

I have  `raw-material` document and `finished-product` document.
What i want to do is on changing the price of `raw-material` i want to update the price of `finished-material`
How can i do so ???
My code is like this so far

```
export const rawMaterialPriceChange = functions.database.ref('/raw-materials/{key}').onUpdate((snapshot)=>{
console.log('My key',snapshot.after.key);
var priceDiff = parseFloat(snapshot.after.val().price)-parseFloat(snapshot.before.val().price);
<HERE I WANT TO REFER ANOTHER DOCUMENT WITH SAME KEY AND UPDATE ITS VALUE
return true;
});
```

My firebase structure is like this:
[image]

Can anyone please help me ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution from the following threads

1. [Firebase HTTP Cloud Functions - Read database once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913139/firebase-http-cloud-functions-read-database-once)
2. [How to run query from inside of Cloud function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868592/how-to-run-query-from-inside-of-cloud-function/42869266#42869266)